# What is a "Hot Question"? Who and how is it defined?

Tags: discussion

How and what and who define a "Hot Question"?
In fact "This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar."
Where have I committed the error?

Comment: [What are the criteria for questions to be selected for Hot Network Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/552049)

Answer (score 4):

"Hot Network questions" are defined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/552049).

But the error message you describe has nothing to do with "hot questions". Rather, it is an explanation for why your question has been closed. Questions are closed if they are not a good fit for our site. For example, [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/192352/education-and-knowledge-preservation) question was just closed. The problem is that it is not a question we can answer.

- Actually, it's not clear what the question is. The only question mark in the post says "is there any global consensus on...this issue?", and it's not clear what "issue" you are referring to.
- My best guess is that you are asking "how much information from my formal education do I need to remember in my active memory?" But this depends on your goals and your philosophy of life; no one on Earth can tell you whether you remember "enough."

I suggest looking at our [site description](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and some of our [all-time top questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes) to see the kinds of things we can help with.

Comment: Thank you. I believe "We" you referred to means humans with voting power/reputation and not Search Engine analytic reports.